# Cannot mount image made with ddrecovery in Fedora

Tags: fedora, mount, ntfs, data-recovery, ddrescue

I have recently made a switch to Fedora. I have an NTFS disk image that I made from a failing hard disk on Ubuntu using ddrecover.

Under Ubuntu, I could mount the image just fine and recover the files, however, in Fedora, it doesn't seem to want to play nice.

So after problems using mount, I see what kpartx can do for me.
It seems to detect properly that it's a 1.0TB Loop Device under Disks. The image was made from an NTFS disk. However, when I try to get it to mount, I get this error:

```
Error mounting /dev/loop0 at /run/media/User/Rock: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000,dmask=0077,fmask=0177" "/dev/loop0" "/run/media/Jesuszilla/Rock"' exited with non-zero exit status 12: Failed to read last sector (1953519615): Invalid argument
HINTS: Either the volume is a RAID/LDM but it wasn't setup yet,
   or it was not setup correctly (e.g. by not using mdadm --build ...),
   or a wrong device is tried to be mounted,
   or the partition table is corrupt (partition is smaller than NTFS),
   or the NTFS boot sector is corrupt (NTFS size is not valid).
Failed to mount '/dev/loop0': Invalid argument
The device '/dev/loop0' doesn't seem to have a valid NTFS.
Maybe the wrong device is used? Or the whole disk instead of a
partition (e.g. /dev/sda, not /dev/sda1)? Or the other way around?
 (udisks-error-quark, 0)
```

What exactly is going on, and is there a way to fix this?

EDIT: Found a solution! I had to run ntfsfix on the disk using:

```
ntfsfix /dev/loop0
```

And then it mounted just fine!

Comment: Welcome to SuperUser! You'll be able to post your solution as an answer soon, it will make it easier for other users who have similar problem to find it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a solution! I had to run ntfsfix on the disk using:

```
ntfsfix /dev/loop0
```

And then it mounted just fine!